# Dúvida Consulta SQL d

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, sql-server-2012

Estou querendo realizar o cálculo na consulta sql em que o resultado é a quantidade de chamados abertos dividido pelo número de dias úteis período escolhido. Ex: Foram abertos 200 chamados no mês e existem 17 dias úteis no mês de maio, então será terás que realizar essa média.

OBS: Já existe uma função de dias úteis que consta abaixo:

```
USE [0800net_PRD]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[dias_uteis]    Script Date: 30/06/2017 11:06:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION  [dbo].[dias_uteis]  (@DATA_INICIAL DATETIME, @DATA_FINAL DATETIME)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CONT INT 

    SET @DATA_INICIAL = (SELECT CAST(@DATA_INICIAL AS DATE) )
    SET @DATA_FINAL = (SELECT CAST(@DATA_FINAL AS DATE ))
    SET @CONT = 0

    WHILE (@DATA_INICIAL <= @DATA_FINAL)
     BEGIN
        IF (DATEPART(DW, @DATA_INICIAL ) IN(1,7) OR @DATA_INICIAL IN (SELECT CAST(FerData AS DATE) FROM Feriado))
         BEGIN
          SET @DATA_INICIAL = @DATA_INICIAL+1
         END

        IF DATEPART(DW, @DATA_INICIAL ) NOT IN(1,7) 
         BEGIN
          SET @CONT = @CONT+1
          SET @DATA_INICIAL = @DATA_INICIAL+1
         END 
     END
RETURN @CONT
END
```

Abaixo é a consulta que estou tentando realizar isso.

```
select
s1.Ano ,s1.Mês , CASE  s1.Mês
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Janeiro'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Fevereiro'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'Março'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'Abril'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'Maio'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'Junho'
         WHEN 7 THEN 'Julho'
         WHEN 8 THEN 'Agosto'
         WHEN 9 THEN 'Setembro'
         WHEN 10 THEN 'Outubro'
         WHEN 11 THEN 'Novembro'
         WHEN 12 THEN 'Dezembro'
       END AS Mês_Extenso, s1.[Média de Abertura Diária], s2.fechamento
from
(select COUNT(SolData)/(SUM(dbo.dias_uteis('01/04/2017', '26/06/2017') + SUM(dbo.dias_uteis('01/04/2017', '26/06/2017'))))[Média de Abertura Diária],
DATEPART(month, SolData) Mês, DATEPART(YEAR, SolData) Ano 
from Solicitacao S inner join usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel and S.UsuIDResponsavel = 29
where S.ProID = 2 and CONVERT(DATE,SolData) BETWEEN '01/04/2017' and '26/06/2017'  group by DATEPART(YEAR, SolData), DATEPART(month,SolData)) s1
inner join
(select COUNT(SolDataFechamento) Fechamento, DATEPART (month, SolDataFechamento) Mês, DATEPART(YEAR, SolDataFechamento) Ano
from Solicitacao S inner join usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel and S.UsuIDResponsavel = 29
where S.ProID = 2 and CONVERT(DATE, SolDataFechamento) BETWEEN '01/04/2017' and '26/06/2017'  group by DATEPART(YEAR, SolDataFechamento), DATEPART(MONTH, SolDataFechamento)) s2
on s1.Mês=s2.Mês and s1.Ano = s2.Ano
order by 
s1.Ano, s1.Mês
```

OBS: Ao executar dá também uma mensagem de erro "Não é possível executar uma função de agregação em uma expressão que contenha uma agregação ou uma subconsulta."

Comment: Coloque a estrutura das tabelas por favor, e o calculo deveria sair no seu resultado, digo no seu select e não no subselect, não ?!

Comment: já tentei fazer tbm sem as subconsultas, mas dá o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Estou querendo realizar o cálculo na consulta sql em que o resultado é a quantidade de chamados abertos dividido pelo número de dias úteis período escolhido.*

Eis uma abordagem diferente do código disponibilizado. Espero que atenda ao que necessita. O código assume que o período de emissão terá meses completos. Isto é, que o período começará em início de mês e terminará em final de mês.

```
-- código #1 v3
--> informe a data inicial e final (formato dd/mm/aaaa)
declare @DataInicial date, @DataFinal date;
set @DataInicial= convert(date, '1/4/2017', 103);
set @DataFinal= convert(date, '30/6/2017', 103);

-- garante sequência nos parâmetros
IF @DataInicial > @DataFinal
  goto _FIM;

-- configuração para a função datename retornar em português
set language Brazilian;

--
with cteSolicAcum as (
SELECT year(S.SolData) as Ano, month(S.SolData) as Mês,
       count(S.SolData) as qtdAbertura,
       count(S.SolDataFechamento) as qtdFechamento
  from Solicitacao as S 
       inner join usuario as U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel 
  where S.UsuIDResponsavel = 29
        and S.ProID = 2 
        and SolData between @DataInicial and @DataFinal
  group by year(S.SolData), month(S.SolData)
)
SELECT Ano, Mês,
       datename(month, datefromparts(Ano, Mês, 1)) as Mês_Extenso,
       qtdAbertura as Abertura,
       cast((cast(qtdAbertura as float) / 
             dbo.dias_uteis(datefromparts(Ano, Mês, 1),
                            eomonth(datefromparts(Ano, Mês, 1))
                           )) as decimal (7,2)) as [Média de Abertura Diária],
       qtdFechamento as Fechamento
  from cteSolicAcum;

_FIM:
go
```

Comment: rapaz, vc é o cara mesmo. É isso ai!, mas só uma duvida.. o resultado trouxe os resultados da media fechado. Teria como trazer com 2 casas decimais?

Comment: @RenanBessa: verifique se o código #1 v3 atende agora ao que necessita.

Comment: ótimo, isso mesmo. Valeu mestre

Answer (score 0):

Vou lhe ajudar com a consulta para retornar o número de dias úteis do mês.

```
declare @startDate datetime = '01/04/2017'
declare @endDate datetime = '30/04/2017'
DECLARE @totaldays INT; 
DECLARE @weekenddays INT;
declare @feriados int;

SELECT @feriados = count(*)
FROM Feriado
where FerData between @startDate and @endDate

SET @totaldays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate) 
SET @weekenddays = ((DATEDIFF(WEEK, @startDate, @endDate) * 2) + -- get the number of weekend days in between
                       CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + -- if selection was Sunday, won't add to weekends
                       CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @endDate) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  -- if selection was Saturday, won't add to weekends

select (@totaldays - @weekenddays - coalesce(@feriados,0))
```

Ainda seria interessante você criar um registro com os feriados, para também diminuir eles dos dias úteis.

Comment: Já existe a tabela feriados. Está na função tbm!

Comment: Fiz uma edição para levar em consideração a tua tabela feriado.

Comment: Ao utilizar *DATEPART(weekday* deve-se definir antes qual é o DATEFIRST desejado. Caso contrário, o resultado pode ser inesperado.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que queira a média de chamados abertos por ano/mês, então ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(YEAR, S.SolData) Ano,
    DATEPART(month, S.SolData) Mes, 
    Count(S.SolID) / 
    dbo.dias_uteis(
        (S.SolData - DAY(S.SolData) + 1),
        DATEADD(DD, -DAY(DATEADD(M, 1, S.SolData)), DATEADD(M, 1,S.SolData))
    ) as media
FROM Solicitacao S 
INNER JOIN usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel 
    AND S.UsuIDResponsavel = 29
WHERE S.ProID = 2 
    AND CONVERT(DATE,S.SolData) BETWEEN '01/04/2017' AND '26/06/2017' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, S.SolData), DATEPART(month, S.SolData)
```

certamente não tive como testar o código e também não tive acesso à estrutura das tabelas. Espero que ajude.

*Edit:*

Apenas para testes, não é a forma mais correta, mas faça um teste:

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(YEAR, S.SolData) Ano,
    DATEPART(month, S.SolData) Mes, 
    (Count(S.SolID) / 
    Count(distinct cast(S.SolData As Date))) as media
FROM Solicitacao S 
INNER JOIN usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel 
    AND S.UsuIDResponsavel = 29
WHERE S.ProID = 2 
    AND CONVERT(DATE,S.SolData) BETWEEN '01/04/2017' AND '26/06/2017' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, S.SolData), DATEPART(month, S.SolData)
```

Comment: ôpa amigo, fico imenso agradecido por está me ajudando, mas infelizmente ainda não retornou a consulta. O erro agora é: "A coluna 'Solicitacao.SolData' é inválida na lista de seleção porque não está contida em uma função de agregação nem na cláusula GROUP BY.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6

Comment: veja se a alteração que coloquei funciona @RenanBessa

Comment: consegue fazer uma função de dias úteis, que receba apenas o ano e mês ?

Comment: testei com essa consulta , porém, deu o seguinte erro agora.Conflito no tipo de operando: date é incompatível com int

Comment: consegue colocar no SQLFiddle ?

Comment: ôpa amigo, bem.. essa consulta que vc me disse funcionou, porém, vc nao mencinou para dividir com o numero de dias uteis: SELECT
    DATEPART(YEAR, S.SolData) Ano,
    DATEPART(month, S.SolData) Mes, 
    (Count(S.SolID) / 
    Count(distinct cast(S.SolData As Date))) as media
FROM Solicitacao S 
INNER JOIN usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel 
    AND S.UsuIDResponsavel = 29
WHERE S.ProID = 2 
    AND CONVERT(DATE,S.SolData) BETWEEN '01/04/2017' AND '26/06/2017' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, S.SolData), DATEPART(month, S.SolData)

Comment: sim, esse código q passei por último, conta como dias úteis, cada dia q houve solicitação. não é o mais correto, mas já dá pra ter uma noção. Você consegue fazer uma função de dias úteis que receba somente mês e ano como parâmetro ?

Comment: pior que to confuso de como realizar essa função de receber mês e ano. Como seria?

Comment: você não pode usar o campo `S.SolData` dentro do script porque se não teria que coloca-lo no group by, então só pode usar `DATEPART(YEAR, S.SolData)` e `DATEPART(MONTH, S.SolData)` que já estão no group by...  teria q ter uma função que recebesse apenas esses dois parâmetros para retornar os dias úteis, dentro da função você deve encontrar o primeiro e último dia do mês para fazer o calculo